# sprintf equivalent for client-side JavaScript

Tags: javascript, binding, printf

I know that `console.log` supports at least some of the basic features of `printf` from C through messing around, but I was curious of a way to take advantage of `console.log`'s implementation to create something similar to `sprintf`. I know you can't simply use `.bind` or `.apply` since `console.log` doesn't actually return the string, so is there a way around this?

If this isn't actually possible, is there some other little-known native implementation that's only a few lines of code away from achieving `sprintf` in JavaScript?

For those who do not know what `sprintf` is exactly, [here is some documentation from tutorialspoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_sprintf.htm). Example usage I'm looking for is below:

```
var string1 = sprintf("Hello, %s!", "world");
var string2 = sprintf("The answer to everything is %d.", 42);
```

Comment: I found the implementation of console.log https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/console.js there doesn't seem to be a way to insert code inbetween anywhere. Best bet would be copy over the format function and build the string your self.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Keep it simple

```
var sprintf = (str, ...argv) => !argv.length ? str : 
    sprintf(str = str.replace(sprintf.token||"$", argv.shift()), ...argv);
```

Since Javascript handles data types automatically, there is no need for type options.

If you need padding, [`"15".padStart(5,"0")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart) = `("00000"+15).slice(-5)` = `"00015"`.

#### Usage

```js
var sprintf = (str, ...argv) => !argv.length ? str : 
    sprintf(str = str.replace(sprintf.token||"$", argv.shift()), ...argv);

alert(sprintf("Success after $ clicks ($ seconds).", 15, 4.569));
sprintf.token = "_";
alert(sprintf("Failure after _ clicks (_ seconds).", 5, 1.569));

sprintf.token = "%";
var a = "%<br>%<br>%";
var b = sprintf("% plus % is %", 0, 1, 0 + 1);
var c = sprintf("Hello, %!", "world");
var d = sprintf("The answer to everything is %.", 42);
document.write(sprintf(a,b,c,d));
```

Comment: I do like the convention of `$` as placeholders, especially since typing is not really strictly necessary in string templating. Thank you for this simple idea.

Answer (score 3):

Try utilizing <strike>`eval`</strike> , `.replace`

```js
var sprintf = function sprintf() {
  // arguments
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)
    // parameters for string
  , n = args.slice(1, -1)
    // string
  , text = args[0]
    // check for `Number`
  , _res = isNaN(parseInt(args[args.length - 1])) 
             ? args[args.length - 1] 
               // alternatively, if string passed
               // as last argument to `sprintf`,
               // `eval(args[args.length - 1])`
             : Number(args[args.length - 1]) 
    // array of replacement values
  , arr = n.concat(_res)
    // `res`: `text`
  , res = text;
  // loop `arr` items
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    // replace formatted characters within `res` with `arr` at index `i`
    res = res.replace(/%d|%s/, arr[i])
  }
  // return string `res`
  return res
};

document.write(sprintf("%d plus %d is %d", 0, 1, 0 + 1) 
               + "<br>" 
               + sprintf("Hello, %s!", "world") 
               + "<br>" 
               + sprintf("The answer to everything is %d.", 42)
              );
```

Comment: That looks neat, but I'm not sure why you have `eval` in there... why can't you just use `parseInt` again?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts `eval` was utilized to evaluate string "0+1" ; updated post passes mathematical expression as `Number`, `+` operator rather than `String` input to avoid using `eval`. Another option at that portion of `sprintf` function could possibly utilize `Function` .